# Multiple Model registration form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently working on a subscription app with rails. I'm trying to figure out the login for a user to start a subscription.

Here are the **models** I plan to use

- User (contains credentials of the user)
- Plan (each plan has a different price_per_month, quantity, etc.)
- Subscription (Contains a start_date, end_date, user_id, plan_id, ...)
- Payment (Contains payment informations such as payment_date, ammount,
  etc...)

**Relationships**

- User has_one Subscription
- Subscription belongs_to Plan
- Subscription belongs_to User
- Subscription has_many Payment

My question is about the creation of a new subscription.
To subscribe, a user has to *signup/login -> select a plan -> then checkout*.

What would be the best way to build this kind of multiple-model form?
Also, the Subscription object is created after the payment.
For example how can I get to know which Plan the User selected after the checkout to fill the plan_id into the Subscription object?

Thanks in advance for helping me see more clearly.

Comment: You're probably going to want to use a `form_tag`. Which of your models are going to have attributes on your form and what are the attributes? On your object creation question, do you have any controller or other logic you can post? It would be good to know where you are starting from. With some more detail, we may be able to help.

Comment: Are you using some sort of third party js payment solutio(recurly, braintree, stripe, etc)?

Comment: @Austio yes I'm planning on using Stripe.